# Prevent HTML content from overlapping

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/pefGx/1/ and for some reason the nav area hides content as opposed to just making it go to the next line.  What kind of code do I need to put in there to make the words move around it.  I have tried putting the ul in a div but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others said, remove the position absolute.  You can then use the margin properties to move it upward if needed.
Here's your JS Fiddle with the nav moved 40px upward

http://jsfiddle.net/pefGx/5/

The key line is margin-top in the css.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `position: absolute;`.

Content won't flow around things that are taken out of normal flow (which is what absolute positioning does).

Comment: well I needed that to have it go to the top.  now it sits about 40px from the top.  any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't do it on the jsfiddle but on my main site it does

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to remove `position:absolute;` from your nav class. And all will be ok.

This is your updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pefGx/4/

Comment: same as above it moves it down when I do that.  anyway to keep it at the top and remove the absolute part?